# send emails automatically through smtp office 365

Tags: smtp, office365, phpmailer

I am having trouble connecting to smtp everytime i am getting "Email could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/TroubleshootingSMTP server error: Failed to connect to server SMTP code: 101 Additional SMTP info: Network is unreachable"

but when iam checking the same with https://dnschecker.org/smtp-test-tool.php its sending. Here is my code -

```
<?php
// Retrieve POST data from FastSpring webhook
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($json, true);

// Extract customer email address from POST data
//$email = $data['customer']['email'];
//$email = $_POST['email'];
$email = 'abc@gmail.com';
//echo "Recipient email: " . $email;

// function getlicensekey($email, $hash) {
    
//     $c = $hash;
//     $length = strlen($email);
//     $myArray = [$length];
    
//     //echo "Hello, $name!";
// }
// Generate license key
//$license_key = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
//echo "Recipient email: " . $license_key;

// Set SMTP email settings
$smtp_host = 'smtp.office365.com'; // Replace with your SMTP server hostname
$smtp_port = 587; // Replace with your SMTP server port number
$smtp_username = 'sales@abc.com'; // Replace with your SMTP server username
$smtp_password = '********'; // Replace with your SMTP server password

// Set email details
$from_email = 'sales@abc.com'; // Replace with your email address
$from_name = 'Sales'; // Replace with your name
$to_email = 'abc@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Your License Key';
$message = "Thank you for purchasing our software. Your license key is: " . $license_key;

// Set up PHPMailer object
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php'; // Include PHPMailer library
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;

require 'src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'src/Exception.php';
require 'src/SMTP.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = $smtp_host;
$mail->Port = $smtp_port;
$mail->Username = $smtp_username;
$mail->Password = $smtp_password;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->setFrom($from_email);
$mail->addAddress($email);
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body = $message;


// Send email
if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Email could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Email has been sent.';
}
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

?>
```

I am tried php mailer but not getting any solution

Comment: As the troubleshooting guide you were given a link to says, it looks like your hosting provider is blocking outbound SMTP. The dnschecker site is on a different server which doesn't have any such blocks, so it has no problem connecting. Quite separately – don't use `md5` for anything; PHP has many better options, especially through the sodium extension (which is installed by default).